# Setting an SPSite to read-only from Application Page

Tags: spsite, read-only

We are trying to make a site read-only from the code-behind of an application page.

When executing the code-snippet from a timer job or a console application it works perfectly, but it throws an

> Access Denied

when run from the code-behind of the application page.

```
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite([Site GUID here])
        {              
            site.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

We have tried reflecting what SharePoint does on the application page in Central Admin, but it was not clear why it works there and not on our page (Some internal methods gets the parameter `RequireCentralAdmin` though, what ever that means)

Any clues?

Answer (score 4):

`RunWithElevatedPrivileges` elevates to the AppPool account of the particular WebApp which might not have permissions to change the SPSite because it is not a Site Collection owner/admin.

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh344224%28v=office.15%29.aspx

> Using highly privileged accounts for application pools or services
>   poses a security risk to the farm, and could allow malicious code to
>   execute.

Instead of using `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, I'd rather use SPUserToken like this:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite([Site GUID here], SPUserToken.SystemAccount)
{              
    site.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

This ensures that the code runs as SharePoint\System which IMHO should have the required permissions.

See also: http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/30/impersonation-elevation-of-privileges

Using SPUserToken also has the additional benefit of being faster because it doesn't change the Windows Security Context like `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` does.

Comment: We tried using your code instead (by impersonation instead of elevation). Nothing changed, still Access Denied if setting read-only to false. Interestingly you can set "WriteLocked", "ReadLocked", "Archived" with our first code. It is just the "ReadOnly" that fails terribly

Comment: I'd some more code to check what account is used with the TimerJob and also what role/permissions it has. I'm starting to believe that FarmAdmin permissions are required.

Comment: But the system account should be Farm admin, right? Or what permissions does this account really hold?

Comment: AFAIK, yes the system account should be FarmAdmin. Another idea is that special content DB permissions are required but missing. Can you try to run your code from an application page deployed under Central Admin?

Comment: That is in idea, but not really doable in our real-life scenario where users should not have access to CA (right now we are reverting to using a timer job, but it feels like a work-around)

Comment: Still looking into this. I remember a change MSFT made back in SP2010 preventing changes on SPFarm and SPWebApplication if derived from SPSite or SPWeb. This issue sounds very similar even if you are trying to change a SPSite property. Just an idea, I'll keep you posted about my findings.